# Linq to Entities with Linq to XML running very slowly

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-xml

I am querying a table and just asking it to return one value. Then building XML with that one value. When I run the query in SSMS, the returned data takes less than a second. If I run it across a VPN, using Linq to Entitities and Linq to XML, I have been waiting for 30-minutes and finally quit. Is there a way to improve the performance?

Here is the code (I'm passing in a vendor object to this procedure, which is a representation of a record in a vendor table):

```
using (Context ctx = new Context())
{
   XElement xe = new XElement("Orders",
      from o in ctx.Orders.ToList()
      where (o.VendorID.Equals(vendor.VendorID) && o.OrderStateID.Equals(3))
      select
         new XElement("Order",
         new XElement("OrderNumber", o.OrderID)));
}
```

Comment: `ToList` before `Where`? This is not LINQ to Entities, you bring the whole table in memory and run LINQ to Objects query.

Answer (score 1):

It will be good to perform the filtering inside the database, rather than reading the whole table in memory and performing LINQ to Objects query (which effectively you do with `ToList` call on `ctx.Orders`).

```
   XElement xe = new XElement("Orders",
      from o in (from o in ctx.Orders
                 where o.VendorID.Equals(vendor.VendorID) && o.OrderStateID.Equals(3)
                 select new { o.OrderID } // Select just the fields needed
                 ).AsEnumerable() // Switch to LINQ to Objects
      select
         new XElement("Order",
         new XElement("OrderNumber", o.OrderID)));
```